# How can I disable ExtDeprecationWarning for external libs in flask

Tags: python, flask

When I run my script, I get this output:

```
/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.sqlalchemy is deprecated, use flask_sqlalchemy instead.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.marshmallow is deprecated, use flask_marshmallow instead.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use flask_cache instead.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.restful is deprecated, use flask_restful instead.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.restful.fields is deprecated, use flask_restful.fields instead.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.restful.reqparse is deprecated, use flask_restful.reqparse instead.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.restplus is deprecated, use flask_restplus instead.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.restful.representations is deprecated, use flask_restful.representations instead.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.script is deprecated, use flask_script instead.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.migrate is deprecated, use flask_migrate instead.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
```

I don't really care about this, because external libs are causing this. I can't update these libs as I don't own them and I see for several there are pull requests pending.

How can I get some peace and quiet?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of Flask 1.0, `flask.ext` does not exist. Packages that haven't fixed these imports will not work.

---

First, you *should* care about this because the packages you're using aren't up to date.  Report a bug that they should switch to using direct import names, such as `flask_sqlalchemy`, rather than the `flask.ext` import hook.

Add a [`warnings.simplefilter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/warnings.html) line to filter out these warnings.  You can place it wherever you're configuring your application, before performing any imports that would raise the warning.

```
import warnings
from flask.exthook import ExtDeprecationWarning

warnings.simplefilter('ignore', ExtDeprecationWarning)
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot decide for sure from your question, but I'm pretty sure it's the imports within your source files that're causing these warnings.

If you are using the deprecated flask.ext import redirect, then for example:

```
flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy()
```

Becomes a direct import:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy()
```

If you're using Linux, this one-liner will make the change in all your files and folders recursively (from ./).

Back up first to a different file path - I cannot say with certainty it will not corrupt the contents of a .git directory, or other svn you use, etc. Or just make the amendments manually.

```
find ./ -type f exec sed -i 's/flask.ext./flask_/g' {} \;
```

Comment: Your assumption is wrong, as clearly pointed out in the question, and as seen in the error log.